# Are masks temporary?

Tags: tera

I got a mask from corsairs stronghold and I went with my mouse over it and it showed me available: *6 days 23 hours*

So I started to wear/soulbind it. When I looked at the mask item while I was wearing it, the *6 days 23 hours* were gone from the item.

Now I wonder wether the mask is temporary or was there just a time limit to soul bind it to yourself?

Comment: Even though I don't play Tera, I can say a rather common pattern in MMOs is allowing people to trade bind-on-equip/bind-on-pickup during a certain period of time IF they were playing in a party. A WoW example, but can easily be relatable: You're playing with your friends trough a dungeon, and you accidentally loot a item that is not recommendedfor you, and that item is "Bind on Pickup", you have 12 hours to trade it with anyone in the same party or raid group as you in the dungeon, but only if you don't equip it. This time is shown on the bottom of the item's tooltip. Maybe this was your case.

Comment: @kroltan Aha okay thanks for the comment though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is temporary. I got it January 27th and it expired February 3rd. Simple answer.